# Find roots of $3z^{100} - e^z$ in the unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

This question was given in an exam in complex analysis:
Let $f \left( z \right) = 3z^{100} - e^z$. Find all of $f$'s roots in $D \left ( 0,1 \right)$ and show that they are simple roots.

I've seen these types of questions with polynomials and the usual technique is to use [Rouche's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9's_theorem) but it seems that the conditions are not satisfied here. Neither function $3z^{100}$ nor $e^z$ is strictly greater than the other in the unit disc.

EDIT: I've misinterpreted the conditions for Rouche's theorem. As mentioned in the comments, the theorem only requires that one function be strictly greater than the other on the boundary of the compact domain (in this case, the unit circle) and indeed that condition is met.

Comment: Well, $3|z|^{100}=|e^z|=e^{\Re z}$ might be easier to solve, first. In particular, $\Re z<0$ necessarily.

Comment: That any such roots are simple roots is just a result of $f'(z)=f'(z)=0$ meaning that $3z^{100} = 300z^{99}$ or $z=0,100$. Neither is a root...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, I don't think $\operatorname{Re} z < 0$ is necessary.  eladidan, look again, one of the functions $3z^{100}$ or $e^z$ *is* strictly greater on the unit circle.

Comment: @AntonioVargas, on $0$, $e^z=1$ is greater than $3z^{100}=0$ and on $1$ for example, $3z^{100}=3$ and $e^z=e<3$

Comment: @eladidan, Rouché's theorem doesn't care about what happens *inside* the unit disk, only about what happens on the *boundary*.

Comment: @AntonioVargas oh boy, what a blunder. Thanks for setting me straight

Comment: Glad to help :)  If you've got one, you can post an answer to your own question here.  I'll happily upvote it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $\left|z \right|=1$ we have that $\left| 3z^{100} \right|  = 3$ and $\left|e^z \right| = \left| e^{ \mathfrak{R}z } \right| \leq e<3$. Thus we have that $\left| 3z^{100} \right|>\left| e^z \right|$ on the unit circle.

Therefore, using Roche's theorem we obtain that $3z^{100}$ and $3z^{100} - e^z$ have the same number of zeros in the unit disc. $3z^{100}$ clearly has a single zero $z=0$ there, of multiplicity 100 and therefore $3z^{100} - e^z$ also has 100 zeroes there.

To show that these zeroes are simple, we can simply differentiate. Let $z_0$ be a zero of $f$ in the unit disc. Observe $f^\prime \left( z \right) = 300z^{99} - e^z$. Assume towards contradiction that $z_0$ is a zero of $f^\prime$. Then $ 300{z_0}^{99} - e^{z_0}=0=3{z_0}^{100}- e^{z_0}$. This yields that $z_0=0$ or $z_0=100$ (not in the unit circle thus we can disregard it), thus $z_0=0$ which is clearly a contradiction since $0$ is not a zero of $f$.